# Building GStreamer plugins and application with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gstreamer

I'm new to GStreamer. I want to add all GStreamer plugin libraries into a Cygwin environment (win32). My goal is to write a small C application with Cygwin, based on the code provided in this blog:

http://felipec.wordpress.com/2008/01/19/gstreamer-hello-world/

If that is possible, could you provide me with the instructions to do so?

thanks and regards,

Sri

Comment: You should update the title of your question to better reflect it.

Comment: Why Cygwin? From what I know, VS (http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/) and Mingw are better supported (I actually work on project using GStreamer Mingw)

Answer (score 0):

You can find instruction on http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-integration-win32.html.

1. Install dependency packages :
   GLib, libxml2, libintl, libiconv
2. Download prebuild library for Win32 here : 
    http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.5.2/

After this, you can develop gstreamer app like other platform.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the gstreamer tutorial programs on cygwin by installing the gstreamer and gtk libraries and carefully following the build instructions found at the bottom of each gstreamer tutorial instruction page found at https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/index.html

I did not need packages from outside of cygwin's installer.